# three.js in,Sprite.render Depth attribute is not supported

Tags: three.js, sprite

This is my code:

```
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(material);
sprite.renderDepth = 10;
```

The above renderDepth setting is invalid, it does not work for sprites.
How to solve this problem？

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? Can you show a simple, live example? -- not your entire project. Answers in this case tend to be case-specific.

Comment: I want to ask you the same question......http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36141/discussion-between-westlangley-and-viclib

Comment: Now in the latest version, this property has not been achieved?？？

Comment: Make it easy for people to help you. Do what I suggested above if you want help finding a work-around.

Comment: that mean set the Z-coord ??

Comment: Edit your question and provide a link to a simple, live example so we know exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_6b83b41b0101jmin.html

Comment: You have only two sprites and you want one of them to always be on top (even if it is farther away from the camera). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.in addition ，when Camera rotation, one of them to always be on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want one sprite to always be on top.

Since `SpriteMaterial` does not support a user-specified `renderDepth`, you have to implement a work-around.

Sprites are rendered last when using `WebGLRenderer`.

The easiest way to do what you want is to have two scenes and two render passes, with one sprite in the second scene like so:

```
renderer.autoClear = false;
scene2.add( sprite2 );
```

then in the render loop

```
renderer.render( scene, camera );
renderer.clearDepth();
renderer.render( scene2, camera );
```

three.js r.64